# Build a new array from an existing using a boolean mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, mask

I have created a boolean mask, say `mask`, which I want to apply to an existing array, say `old` to create an entirely new one, say `new`, which retains only the non zero elements. The `new` array should then have a smaller dimension with respect to `old`.

Can some one suggest me the fastest and more coincise way, without using, if possible, the numpy.append function?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with inputs, and desired output

Answer (score 1):

Say you have:

```
old = np.array([2,4,3,5,6])
mask = [True, False, True, False, False]
```

Simply do:

```
new = old[mask]
print(new)
[2 3]
```

I suggest you read about [Boolean or “mask” index arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just use logical indexing

```
x = x[x!=0]
```